# Merge two lists element wise in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of the same class and same length. I wish to merge them element by element based on a custom function.

I want to merge those pairs of elements that appear at the same position in their lists.

I have the following two lists:

```
            public class classA
            {
                public classA() { }

                public int id { get; set; }
                public string email { get; set; }
                public string name { get; set; }
            }
            var users1 =
                new List<classA> {
                    new classA{ 
                                id= 1,
                                email = "Test1@Test.com"
                    },
                    new classA{
                                id= 2,
                                email = "Test2@Test.com"
                    }
                };

            var users2 =
                new List<classA> {
                    new classA{ 
                                id= 456,
                                email = "Test1@Test.com",
                                name = "Test One"
                    },
                    new classA{ 
                                id= 123,
                                email = "Test2@Test.com",
                                name = "Test Two"
                    }
                };
```

I wish to merge them to get the following list:

```
{ 
 {
  id=1,
  email="Test1@Test.com",
  name="Test One"
 },
 { 
  id=2,
  email="Test2@Test.com",
  name="Test Two"
 }
}
```

Comment: What are the rules for *merging*?  It appears that you either take the `id` property from the first list, or you take the lowest numbered `id`.  Do you base the identity on the email address (in the very small example you show, both inputs to a "merge" share the same email address)?  What happens if the email addresses differ?

Comment: `List.AddRange(...)` ?

Comment: As @Flydog57 already pointed out, you have to specify what the rules for merging are. Under the assumption that you want to merge those pairs of elements that appear at the same position in their lists, the first step is to use the Linq method Zip to create Tuples of elements. The second step is then to merge them using the Select method.

Comment: @Đøharrrck, Could you please share the code for it? Yes, I wish to merge those pairs of elements that appear at the same position. C[i] = Somemergefunction(A[i],B[i])

Comment: Like in TJ Rockefeller's answer below (where the selector delegate is directly included in the Zip call).

Comment: There should be no need to create a third list. Just loop through users1 and set the name property to the value of the current index of users2[i].name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have suggested in the comments, I think the LINQ method that you are looking for is [Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netcore-3.1)

```cs
var users3 = users1.Zip(users2,
    (first,second) => new classA{id = first.id, email = first.email, name = second.name});
```

The above will create a new list that takes the `id` and `email` from the first list and `name` from the second list. Order of the lists matter as to how things are merged, and I just chose to handle the merge this way to get the example output that you said you wanted. I will leave it to you to figure out what your actual merging rules should be.